# Ubuntu 23.04 failed to install

Tags: system-installation, 23.04

After following the Ubuntu setup it says *Installation failed*. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not tell us specifically which 23.04 you're installing. Ubuntu 23.04 is available as a server install, and whilst your system appears more like a desktop install to me - two installers are available selected by the ISO you download and use. Why not tell us which you opted to use, instead of making us guess?  Is it Ubuntu Desktop, if it is, which ISO did you try?  Did you try a alternate installer?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Is there no option to see the logs for a more descriptive explanation of the failure? Without knowing *why* the installation failed, it will be incredibly difficult to offer an answer 

Comment: ok I added an image of the iso I downloaded I'm gonna try installing it again and I'll make sure to take a photo of the error message

Comment: The picture you provided has two links available - how are we to know which Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop link you clicked to download from a picture of multiple choices?   *There is a green download button, a blue legacy-desktop-installer button below that, plus a link to the alternative downloads... ie. please be specific as to which you downloaded*  (*or are you saying you tried them all?*)

Comment: Sorry, the big green button lol

Comment: As per my first comment, why not try out the alternate desktop install?  (the "*Legacy Desktop Installer*" is how its described on your link)

Comment: Ok i'll try that. is there a difference between the two ?

Comment: The difference is NIL when installed....   The ISOs however use different installers, the one you downloaded & tried is the new `ubuntu-desktop-installer` which being new, has issues on some hardware, thus the provision of the alternate ISO which uses the *tried & tested* `ubiquity` installer Ubuntu Desktop (and most *flavors* too) has used for years...  The installer used is the difference - why I'm suggesting you try it.

Comment: Ok so if I'm understanding you right I should try the legacy desktop installer. (the button under the green one?)

Comment: Yep... that's what I'd try... It uses the older installer that Canonical hopes to retire (*when the get all the bugs in the `ubuntu-desktop-installer` fixed*).  As stated, the end product of the installer will be identical regardless of which you use (*of the first two options*), the second *legacy* option is there for people like you that have problems with the newer installer.  FYI:  If you get asked to file a bug report on your failed install, please do so, as that will help developers find & fix the problems with the newer `ubuntu-desktop-installer`

Comment: hey thanks a lot I'll try that

Comment: So I tried the legacy installer and it came up with another error. I added the picture to the question

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  Did you burn DVD as slowly as possible, and check the media afterwards?  Ever run a memory check?   Your problem could be hardware, or software.

Comment: The input-output errors are usually either caused by a faulty installation media (verify checksums of your iso, and verify the USB drive after flashing), or due to a faulty hard drive (in which case, you will have to replace it).

Comment: well, I am using a brand new 64GB Sandisk SSD. I don't see how that could be the problem. I've also tried different hard drives but always the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Ubuntu just installed. This time I used the legacy installer (like before) but used a USB stick instead of an SD card with a USB adapter. (maybe this was the problem all along, I didn't have a USB stick handy and I read SD cards work as well). I also didn't format the USB stick (in Rufus) to NTFS (like I did with the SD card) but left it at FAT32. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there among your images: `Error 5 Input/Output Error`

Re-read that. It tells you what to do next.

It's a hardware fault that cannot be fixed by software.

Comment: well I used an sd card formatted to NTFS